# Green's function for a 1D poisson equation with periodic boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, greens-function

I have to find $\varphi(x)$ such that 
$$\frac{d^{2}\varphi(x, y)}{dx^{2}}=\gamma\delta(x-y)$$
with the condition $\varphi(x, y)=\varphi(x+L, y)$. The standard approach is to expand in Fourier series
$$\varphi(x, y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\varphi_{n}(y)\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi{i}nx}{L}\Big)$$
This leads to
$$-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\neq{0}}\varphi_{n}(y)\Big(\frac{2\pi{n}}{L}\Big)^{2}\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi{i}nx}{L}\Big)=\gamma\delta(x-y)$$
Now we multiply by $\exp\Big(-\frac{2\pi{i}mx}{L}\Big)$ and integrate in $[0, L]$ to give
$$-L\varphi_{m}(y)\Big(\frac{2\pi{m}}{L}\Big)^{2}=\gamma\exp\Big(-\frac{2\pi{i}my}{L}\Big)$$
So, the fourier coefficients are
$$\varphi_{m}=-\frac{L\gamma}{(2\pi)^{2}}\frac{\exp\Big(-\frac{2\pi{i}my}{L}\Big)}{m^{2}}$$
However, how do we find the $m=0$ term?

Comment: Why not do the integration separately in the case m=n=0, seeing as there are no sinusoid terms anymore?

Comment: This leads to the absurd like $\gamma=0$

Comment: I do not see where you get that. Try including this calculation in the question.

Comment: Ha, I see. There is no $n=0$ term in the third line, thus the $\varphi_{m}(y)$'s determined are valid for all $m\neq{0}$, however, $\varphi_{0}(y)$ is still to be determined, but how? I've edited the question.

Comment: Just integrate both sides without multiplying by a sinusoid, this gets the coefficient of the constant term.

Comment: When I do so, I get $\gamma=0$...

Comment: Why? You should get $\int_0^L \phi_0(y) dx =L\phi_0(y) = \gamma \int_0^L \delta(x-y) dx = \gamma$. Thus $\phi_0$ is a constant $\gamma/L$.

Comment: But there is now $\varphi_{0}(y)$ term in there, you have $\varphi(x, y)=\varphi_{0}(y)+\sum_{n\neq0}\varphi_{n}(y)\exp\Big(\frac{2\pi{in}x}{L}\Big)$, when differentiated with respect to $x$, you loose $\varphi_{0}(y)$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to do the derivatives beforehand. So that means that the DE doesn't tell you anything about $\phi_0$, only the boundary conditions can do that (and maybe they do or don't, it depends).